# Date creation using different columns in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Having a data frame as below:

| Day | Month and year |
| --- | --- |
| 13 | septiembre /98 |
| 15 | August/98 |
| 24 | Novem /98 |

Is it possible that i can merge day with month and year and create a new column.

| Day | Month and year | Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 13 | septiembre /98 | 13-09-98 |
| 15 | August/98 | 15-08-98 |
| 24 | Nov /98 | 24-11-98 |

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53645882/pandas-merging-101

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to create a panda Series that converts the data you provided from a list to a new list, and then obtains a panda Series from the new, correctly formatted list. I'm not sure if that's what you wanted, but anyway I hope this can be of some help:

```
import pandas as pd

day = [13, 15, 24]
monthyear = ['Semptember/98', 'August/98', 'November/98'] 
daymonthyear = zip(day, monthyear)
daymonthyear_new = []

for i in daymonthyear:
    teste = [i[0],i[1].split("/")]
    string = str(teste[0]) + "-" + str(teste[1][0]) + "-" + 
    str(teste[1][1])

print('string= ', string)
daymonthyear_new.append(string)

print('daymonthyear_new= ', daymonthyear_new)

import datetime

dates = pd.Series(daymonthyear_new)

dates
```

Answer (score 0):

You could perform string slicing and concatenation provided that your dataset comes in a predictable and standard format. Cast this new string to datetime using the `pd.to_datetime` method.

For example, this would work for your example:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([[13, 'Septiembre /98'], [15, 'August/98'], [24, 'Novem /98']], columns=["Day", "Month and year"])
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(
    df['Day'].astype('str') +
    ' - ' +
    df['Month and year'].str.slice(0, 3) +
    ' - ' +
    df['Month and year'].str.slice(-2)
)

print(df)
```

```bash
   Day  Month and year       Date
0   13  Septiembre /98 1998-09-13
1   15       August/98 1998-08-15
2   24       Novem /98 1998-11-24
```